# Custom Drag and Drop Component: When i add a skin, drag and drop no longer works?

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop

I have a skinnableContainer that acts as a container for other drag and droppable items. This container's drop functionality is added from it's parent at the same moment the container is added.

This all works fine until I add a skin class to the skinnableContainer, now none of the draggable items can drop into the container as it did before.

I assume that the Group component wrapping the content from within the skin is acting as a block somehow, but I'm not sure how to allow the drop functionality through it?

Any ideas?

EDIT skin code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" alpha.disabled="0.5">

<fx:Metadata>
    [HostComponent("spark.components.SkinnableContainer")]
</fx:Metadata> 

<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>

<!-- layer 1: border -->
<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" radiusX="5" radiusY="5">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="0" alpha="0.50" weight="1" />
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>

<s:Group id="contentGroup" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"  >
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
</s:Group>
</s:Skin>
```

Comment: No code: can't help. Oh well, a wild guess then: is there any transparency in that custom skin?

Comment: I added the skin code above. There is an alpha='0.5' in the solid color stroke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom skin has no background fill, hence it's completely transparent except for the border. Because of this there is no "hitzone" to drop your items on (right now you will probably be able to drop them if you target exactly that 1px border).

The solution - obviously - is to give it a fill. No worries, if you want it to look transparent, just set its `alpha` to `0`.

```
<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" radiusX="5" radiusY="5">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor alpha="0" />
    </s:fill>
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke alpha="0.50" />
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>
```